# DetectIidSpike() with streaming data

Tags: ml.net

Most of the examples of [DetectIidSpike](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.ml.timeseriescatalog.detectiidspike?view=ml-dotnet#Microsoft_ML_TimeSeriesCatalog_DetectIidSpike_Microsoft_ML_TransformsCatalog_System_String_System_String_System_Int32_System_Int32_Microsoft_ML_Transforms_TimeSeries_AnomalySide) load data from a file or an array in memory and train and run the model using this data. 
What about load a saved model (created with the previous approach), and apply the model on incoming individual data points (from a data stream), so we can evaluate the anomalies on each one. Is that possible? How can it be done? Any examples, points? Thanks!